# How to know a given file is a valid bitcoin wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat, bitcoin-core-development, e-wallet

If I have many files on my hard drive (possibly with different names/extension), how can I test which file is a valid bitcoin wallet.dat ?

Maybe there is some string that exists in every bitcoin wallet ?

I guess I am asking about the format of the data inside the wallet. 
If wallets are different depending on the bitcoin client, then I want to know about bitcoin core.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention but these files WERE on a Linux OS. So there should be some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you can use the `file` command. If the file is a Bitcoin wallet, you should see

```
wallet.dat: Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
```

(It will always say Berkley DB version 9, but the filename might be different.)

`file` is also availible on Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

How does `file` tell that it's a Berkley DB file? See [How did file identify this wallet file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244502/how-did-file-identify-this-particular-file)

Comment: Installing Linux just a sec...

Comment: @marshalcraft actually I *am* using a Linux computer, I forgot to mention, edited question now.